# random.randint() generating a consistent pattern

Tags: python, random, pygame

I've been working on a grid-based application using `pygame`, and have run into a strange problem.

I'm generating a `list` of tiles, each of which can have 1 of 3 random colours. Every time I run the program, though, I get a fairly consistent pattern.

[image: Test 1]

[image: Test 2]

[image: Test 3]

All these tests were right after each other, and similar results were on all runs before the tests, having a giant single-coloured blob in the bottom right.

**This is my tile code**

```
from enum import Enum


class Colour(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3


class Tile():

    def __init__(self, _map, x : int, y : int, colour = 1):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.map = _map
        self.colour = Colour(colour)

    def PrintInfo(self):
        print("x: " + str(self.x) + "\ny: " + str(self.y) + "\nCol: " + str(self.colour.name))
```

**This is where an array of tiles is made, (where the random number is generated)**

```
from Tile import Tile
from random import randint
"""Map class creates a 2d array of tiles, and allows individual tiles, or
groups of tiles to be returned."""


class Map:
    def __init__(self, width : int, height : int):
        self.map = []

        #Create a 2d array of tiles.
        self.map = [[Tile(self, i, j, randint(1, 3)) for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]



    def PrintInfo(self):
        #Print the info of each tile. use GetTile(x, y).PrintInfo() tp get
        #individual tile into
        for t in self.map:
            t.PrintInfo()

    def GetTile(self, x: int, y: int):
        #Get tile from coords
        return self.map[x][y]
```

**This is where the visual component is made, based off a random number**

```
def Main(self):
    #Create an array of data objects
    self.map = Map(8, 8)
    #Create dictionary to connect data object to display object
    self.tileToObjDict = {}

    for i in range(8):#change these from constants after testing
        for j in range(8):
            t = self.map.GetTile(i, j)#get tile at current position in loop
            #t.PrintInfo()
            bobj = BoxObject(self.win, t.x*self.gridSpacing, t.y*self.gridSpacing, t.x*self.gridSpacing+self.gridSpacing,
                             t.y*self.gridSpacing+self.gridSpacing, str(t.colour.name).lower())#Create onject based on info
            self.objects.append(bobj)#add display object to render list
            self.tileToObjDict[t] = bobj#connect tile to display obj in dictionary
```

**Not needed, but code of assembled visual component**

```
#Basic Object

    class BoxObject(Object):
        def __init__(self, surface, x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0, y2 = 0, colour = 'grey', hitbox = Hitbox(EventManager())):#Take a surface, 4 coords, a colour, and an optional hitbox to manage events
            super().__init__(Box(surface, Rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2).GetCorners(),ColourManager().GetColour(colour)),
                hitbox)
            
            #draw the object for 1 frame to reference
            self.drawn = draw.rect(self.graphic.surface, self.graphic.colour,(self.graphic.coord1, self.graphic.coord2))
    
        def Update(self):
            if self.visible:#Draw the object
                draw.rect(self.graphic.surface, self.graphic.colour,(self.graphic.coord1, self.graphic.coord2))
                if Hitbox == None:
                    return
                if len(self.hitbox.eventM.eventList) > 0:#If the hitbox has any events to manage, manage them
                    for e in self.hitbox.eventM.eventList:
                        e()
```

**Colour Module**

```
from pygame import Color

class ColourManager:
    colourDict : {}#holds custom colours

    def __init__(self, defaultColours = True):
        self.colourDict = {}

        if defaultColours:
            self.AddBasicColours()

    def AddColour(self, name : str, _r : int, _g : int, _b : int, _a : int = 255):
        self.colourDict[name] = Color(_r, _g, _b, _a)
    
    def GetColour(self, name : str) -> Color:
        return self.colourDict.get(name)

    def PrintColours(self):
        for key in self.colourDict.keys():
            print(key)

    def AddBasicColours(self):
        self.AddColour('red', 255, 0, 0)
        self.AddColour('green', 0, 255, 0)
        self.AddColour('blue', 0, 0, 255)

        self.AddColour('grey', 100, 100, 100)

    def LoadColourSheet():
        """TODO: Allow many colours to be loaded at once from txt file"""
```

Any help is appreciated, on either an effective alternative randomization method, or a problem with my code that could be causing this issue.

Comment: all pseudo-random generators (no matter how complex) eventually repeat themselves. In any case try using another PRNG, even a custom one

Comment: @NikosM. Eventually, yes, but that should take a very long time. Not what the OP is seeing.

Comment: You select a random number out of only out of 3 numbers, and you see 3 different patterns. I don't see an issue there.

Comment: Exactly the OP has very limited random choices, so patterns are very easy to form or repeat.

Comment: There is too much code to call this a practical minimal example, but at a guess: the colours are properly random, but the pattern is definitely not. This line, `BoxObject(self.win, t.x*self.gridSpacing, t.y*self.gridSpacing, t.x*self.gridSpacing+self.gridSpacing,
                             t.y*self.gridSpacing+self.gridSpacing, str(t.colour.name).lower())#Create onject based on info`, sets a pattern that is pretty much fixed, and `self.map = [[Tile(self, i, j, randint(1, 3)) for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]` defines `t.x` and `t.y` indirectly, also as fixed values.

Answer (score 1):

9769953 was right about it being the pattern and not the randomization. I forgot about how pygame rendered shapes, and the same pattern was because of single blocks being way bigger than they should have been.
I had to change the x2 and y2.

```
        #Box object: screen to draw it to, x1, y1, x2, y2, colour (x1, y1) = top left corner  of box, x2 = width, y2 = height
        bobj = BoxObject(self.win, t.x*self.gridSpacing, t.y*self.gridSpacing, self.gridSpacing, self.gridSpacing, str(t.colour.name).lower())#Create object based on info
```